# Using SimpleSession Storage in a WPF/Winform/WindowsService Client project

Tags: .net, s#arp-architecture

There is a requirement for a WPF client and Windows Service for an
existing S#arp Architecture project and I was wondering what
ISessionStorage to use? I have used SimpleSessionStorage in some of my
integration tests already and the Northwind sample test project also
use the same in MappingIntegrationTests. I have also heard that the
Contrib project is going to have support for Winforms and
WindowsService but I haven't found any ISessionStorage implementation
in that specific to Winforms/WPF/WindowService. So I am assuming
SimpleSessionStorage should work for both WPF/Winform and Windows
Service?

[Same question on Google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture/browse_thread/thread/747807b9789ad181?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nabeel,
    If you are going to use the UnitOfWork or Transaction attribute from the S#arpArchitecture.Contrib project, then you would need to use the ThreadSessionStorage that is in the contrib. If not, then you would use the SimpleSessionStorage

Alec